# How can I extract the text from the <em> tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I tried to extract the Date from-  http://www.oecd.org/tax/tax-policy/

I want to extract the Updated Date (ex: Tax policy measures taken so far (database, Xlsm), updated 29 June 2020) for the 1st one

```
url = 'http://www.oecd.org/tax/tax-policy/'
Res = requests.get(url)
soup= BeautifulSoup(Res.text, 'lxml')

UL = soup.find('ul', {'class':'pub-1-col-list'})

for ul in UL:
    ul= ul.find("em")
    print(ul, ul.next_sibling)
```

i tried using above code it gives **AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'next_sibling'**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url  = 'http://www.oecd.org/tax/tax-policy/'
Res  = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(Res.text, 'html.parser')

EM = soup.select('ul.pub-1-col-list em')

for em in EM:
    print(em.text, em.next_sibling)
```